# How to remove link preview when commenting using graph api (php sdk)

Tags: php, facebook, graph

So i have my code to post a comment with a link in it. However, when it comments, it has the preview of the link in the comment. This is what i mean: http://www.adweek.com/socialtimes/facebook-comment-previews/265863?red=if

```
$toComment = array('message' => 'http://someurlblahblahblah.com')
```

It automatically posts the url preview, how do I stop this?

Comment: You can’t stop that, Facebook does it automatically.